# How do I listen to all user input in a page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I listen to all user input in a page with javascript? At least all keyboard and mouse input. Is there an event for that? Multiple events?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Comment: What you can do is to write a function, and bind that to elements, for the events you want.

Answer (score 0):

[codepen](https://codepen.io/ken001/pen/xxOEwWJ)

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')

inputs.forEach(el => {
   el.addEventListener('input', function (ev) {
      const { target } = ev
      const { type, checked, value } = target
      
      if(type === 'text') {
         console.log(type, value)
      } 
      
      if(['checkbox', 'radio'].includes(type)) {
         console.log(type, checked, value)
      }
   })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" value="">

<label>
   <input type="checkbox" checked value="checkbox"> Checkbox
</label>

<label>
   <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1"> Radio1
</label>
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2"> Radio2
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As specify you can find a list of event in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event)

if you want to catch every keydown on your webpage and get the key code, you can add this event for example :

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
   console.log(event.keyCode)
});
```

or if you want to catch mouse position :

```js
onmousemove = event => {
    console.log("mouse location:", event.clientX, event.clientY);
}
window.addEventListener("mousemove", onmousemove);
```